# Upgrade to 5.24 failed

Tags: upgrade

I tried upgrading to 5.24 and it hung half way through the upgrade - while upgrading to 5.24alpha1.  Here's all that was in the log - it then died. I've gone back to 5.23.4 (Drupal).  Ideas?

Apr 02 09:21:30  [info] Running task: Cleanup old files

Apr 02 09:21:31  [info] Running task: Checking extensions

Apr 02 09:21:31  [info] Running task: Begin Upgrade to 5.24.alpha1

Apr 02 09:21:32  [info] Running task: Upgrade DB to 5.24.alpha1

Apr 02 09:21:33  [info] Running task: Upgrade DB to 5.24.alpha1: SQL

Apr 02 09:21:34  [info] Running task: Install sequential creditnote extension

Comment: Did it succeed in installing that extension?  Are there any errors in webserver logs, or CMS logs?

Comment: I restored the database, which is shared with Drupal, so the only thing I have is the above log.  I'll retry the upgrade and look further

Comment: I ran the upgrade again, nothing in civicrm_log or Drupal's log, nothing more in ConfigAndLog, and no extension installed. I can try again with some diagnostics.  Also I do have a lot of extensions, I could do some gradual disabling.  This is a test system, by the way!

Comment: Ok, since it's a test system would be interesting to try installing that extension manually after the upgrade has failed and see if you get more error messages that way.

Comment: (a) +1 for disabling some other ext's as debug tactic. (b) You might get better debug info with one of these patches: https://gist.github.com/totten/96aa7172faced3fde2225e145307f3b9 (c) You might also get more debug info with a CLI runner (eg `cv upgrade:db -vvv`).

Comment: I had a similar experience on Wordpress 5.4. I cleared cache and used the "Upgrade CiviCRM" option in Christian Wach's CiviCRM Admin Utilities plugin for Wordpress, which is my typical routine. My upgrade also stalled at the same spot that Andy showed. At the time, I didn't think to check on the status of the creditnote extension. I restored my database (mine is separate from Wordpress) and tried again with "cv -vvv upgrade:db". It upgraded with no complaints.

Comment: I don't do command line stuff (I'm strictly an implementer) so tried installing Tim's patches manually but failed. The creditnote extension can only be installed via the command line, it seems, so Aidan's suggestion is out. Since Mark also hit the same problem it doesn't sound like disabling extensions will fix. Any other ideas?

Comment: I uninstalled all extensions and tried again.  It stopped at the same place (5.24aplha1) for a bit, then continued and installed OK, and I now have the sequential creditnote extension installed. There were over 20 extensions disabled so no idea which was the culprit. Is see that three of us have had this upgrade fail now..

Answer (score 4):

I was able to reproduce a similar symptom in a [wp-demo configuration](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit/tree/master/app/config/wp-demo). Specifically, the upgrader activates the new, core-internal extension (`sequentialcreditnotes`), and the activation fired off a general system-flush, and the general system-flush raised an error while handling some data from another extension (`civivolunteer`). The problem only occurred with the web-based upgrade UI (and not with the CLI-based upgrader).

[CiviCRM 5.24.1](https://download.civicrm.org/about/5.24.1) has a fix for that case.

Answer (score 0):

On WordPress version, tried to upgrade from 5.21.2 to 5.24.0 twice and had the same issue. Freezes on: Executed: Upgrade DB to 5.24.alpha1: SQL Had to restore previous day's back up to bring database back. No error messages, just the freezing.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this problem. The following fixed it for me: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/16971

Comment: I saw the same under Joomla.  My test Joomla instance ran to completion, but the CiviCRM menu disappeared!

Comment: Glad you found a fix, Tim and thanks for letting us know . I'm surprised this didn't occur  in testing as it was such a solid error.